# Why does the clean.text() function change word frequencies?

Tags: text-mining, tm

I am doing text analysis and reading articles into R. When I use the clean.text() function from TextReg to clean the text of a corpus and then look up word frequencies using term_stats() from tm, the word frequencies are different from when I don't use clean.text(). I am not stemming words or dropping stop words either, just using clean.text to clean the punctuation and white space. What could explain differences in word counts just by running clean.text() or not?